# multiple font-variation-settings in jQuery .css

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to manipulate a variable font with two axis to respond to the device orientation of my mobile phone. However it only works for the first of the two values i am trying to change in css.

```
$('#thething').css('font-variation-settings', '"wght"' + alpha*100, '"wdth"' + beta*100);
```

The outcoming css syntax would have to look like this:

```
#thething {font-variation-settings: 'wght' VARIABLEALPHA, 'width' VARIABLEBETA};
```

How can I change the code to make it work for both variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way :

`$('#thething').css('font-variation-settings', "'wght'" + alpha*100 + ", 'wdth'" + beta*100);`

In your code, the coma is not in your string parameter.